# How to make large image fit to small stackpanel in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a StackPanel and an image. My image is larger than StackPanel so it just display a part of image. My expectation is image will fit to stackpanel and preserves its native aspect ratio.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="IllustrationStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image x:Name="IllustrationImage"
                   Source="a.png"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                   Stretch="None"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

could you give me some solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Set the Stretch property on the Image to Uniform (instead of None)

> The content is resized to fit in the destination dimensions while it
>   preserves its native aspect ratio.

[MSDN has some examples of the different values you can use](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Or do not set the property at all, as its default value is already Uniform.